# Limit SAMBA directory listing

Tags: samba, directory, access-control-list

Maybe this isn't possible, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I have a samba share that uses ACLs.  The default group can see everything inside the share and has read/write permissions.  I want to create a subfolder inside the top level of the share, then create a corresponding group to that folder.  I'd like members of the **subfolder** group to be able to browse to `\\server\share\subfolder` without being able to see what's inside `\\server\share` except for only `subfolder`.

So to the default group it would show as:

```
Share
--Folder1
--Folder2
--Folder3
--Subfolder
```

and to the **subfolder** group it would show as:

```
Share
--Subfolder
```

Best alternative I've been able to find is grant **subfolder** group traverse permissions and make them connect directly to the folder they're trying to get to: `\\server\share\subfolder`.

I'm implementing this on OS X Server so all usual ACLs are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the

```
hide unreadable
```

option in smb.conf

Comment: I thought that only worked for files?

Comment: I use `hide files = lost+found`: it proves that dirs are also excluded :) Remember: in UNIX, `everything is a file`. Directory is also some sort of a file ;)

Comment: I tried this but got mixed results.  The directory showing up wasn't the directory the user had access to.  We decided to just use the full path to the directory, which is working fine for the most part.